# Function is not defined when called in page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When I call a function normally, it works, but when I call it in `page.evaluate()`, the function is not defined. Here's a demo:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    page.on('console', msg => console.log(msg.text())) // so console.log() works in page.evaluate()
    const test = () => console.log('works')
    await test() // it runs

    await page.evaluate(() => test()) // ReferenceError: test is not defined
})()
```

Comment: This is expected. `evaluate`'s callback [runs in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304665/how-to-pass-a-function-in-puppeteers-evaluate-method), so it doesn't have access to your Node state. What are you trying to achieve here (I assume something more interesting than logging "works")?

Comment: It depends. Please read the dupe thoroughly because it should cover most/all use cases. The question is, do you want the  func you invoke to run in the browser console or in Node? If the former, then you can use `addScriptTag` or use a previous (or the same) `evaluate` to attach functions to the window. That's what I'd do for your delay example (although [delaying is bad](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout)). if you want to trigger Node code, use `exposeFunction`.

Comment: [How do I expose an object with a bunch of functional definitions (or methods) to puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72156753/how-do-i-expose-an-object-with-a-bunch-of-functional-definitions-or-methods-to/72157472#72157472) may also help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page context that Puppeteer spawns (in its virtual browser) is not the same as the Node context that you write the implementation code in. When `page.evaluate` is passed a function, that function is serialized, then passed to the browser, and deserialized and evaluated (in that different context). Here, the page context doesn't have access to `test`, because that variable is only defined in Node, not on the page.

You can put a function into the page if you want, though, by defining it in the page context.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  window.test = () => console.log('works');
});
await page.evaluate(() => test())
```

or

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const test = () => console.log('works');
  test();
});
```