# How do I define a named function within page.evaluate without a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have a playwright Page object on which I want to evaluate some code.
Since I need to do one thing several times inside the evaluation, I want to define that piece of code in a function like so:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const foo = (): string => "foo";

    return foo();
  });
```

But whenever I run anything that assigns a function to a variable, I get the following error during execution.

```
await page.evaluate: ReferenceError: __name is not defined
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:226:30), <anonymous>:1:16)
    at UtilityScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:228:17)
    at UtilityScript.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)
```

I can fix it by assigning the function to something like `window.foo = () => "foo"` and then calling that. But I don't understand why this is an error in the first place.
It does not make a difference whether I use an arrow function or not.
If I just define a non-callable variable, I can use it just fine within the `evaluate` context.

So how do I define a function without assigning it to some global object for use withing evaluate, and why is a callable variable special in the first place?
This is all within a single call to `evaluate`, it does not need to persist.

If I don't assign it, but keep it anonymous it works fine, and if it's not callable, it also works fine, and assigned to some object it works:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    return ((): string => "foo")();
  });

await page.evaluate(() => {
    const x = "foo";
    return x;
  });

await page.evaluate(() => {
    window.foo = () => "foo";
    return window.foo();
  });
```

Just defining it in the browser console obviously also works:

[image: defining a named function in browser console]

This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710551/function-is-not-defined-when-called-in-page-evaluate), because I want to define the function within the call, not outside of it. I understand that there is serialization to send it to the browser, which I don't need here since I am only defining it once already in the browser.
The 2. answer on that question even does what I am trying to do.

**Edit**:
Here is a minimal example the causes the error on my machine:

```
  const { chromium } = await import("@playwright/test");
  const server = await chromium.launchServer();
  const client = await chromium.connect(server.wsEndpoint());
  const browser = await client.newContext.bind(client)();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const shouldBeFoo = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const foo = () => "foo";

    return foo();
  });

// ReferenceError: __name is not defined
```

This snippet reliably triggers the error on my machine, even with this contrived example where it of course does not make sense to have the function in the first place. There is no bigger picture needed than this, there is nothing else I am doing.

If I debug into the evaluate call into playwright, I land here:

```
  async evaluate(pageFunction, arg) {
    (0, _jsHandle.assertMaxArguments)(arguments.length, 2);
    return await this._mainFrame.evaluate(pageFunction, arg);
  }
```

There is already something that seems wrong at this point: the "pageFunction" argument is a function that reads like this in the debugger: `()=>{const foo=__name(()=>"foo","foo");return foo()}`.
Calling it at this point still works.

Inside `_mainFrame.evaluate`, it gets stringified, I am assuming this has something to do with it:

```
const result = await this._channel.evaluateExpression({
      expression: String(pageFunction),
      isFunction: typeof pageFunction === 'function',
      arg: (0, _jsHandle.serializeArgument)(arg)
    });
```

This might also just be a bug in playwright.

Comment: I suspect the "why" is "because something is happening in the normalization code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/1539cde0343a19bfa590478cb13bb9aeff905180/packages/playwright-core/src/server/javascript.ts#L260-L262)"...

Comment: These code blocks work fine for me. I'm assuming you're `await`ing the `evaluate` call. Please share a runnable [mcve] I can copy into my code, hit run, and see the problem. Showing an actual use case is important, or at least preserving whatever context is necessary to ensure it fails--it could be that these simplified examples skip some critical information. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged both Puppeteer and Playwright? I'm going to remove the Puppeteer tag until it's clarified how that's relevant.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? In other words , what is the functional validation you are trying to put in place? Can you provide some application testing context here so that we can see the bigger picture?

Answer (score 1):

[Unable to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218772/how-do-i-define-a-named-function-within-page-evaluate-without-a-referenceerror/78220169#comment137899675_78218772):

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.42.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.firefox.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const foo = () => "foo";
    return foo();
  });
  console.log(result); // => foo

  // it also works using a string:
  const result2 = await page.evaluate(`;(() => {
    const foo = () => "foo";
    return foo();
  })();`);
  console.log(result2); // => foo
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: May I know why you are placing a semicolon in the beginning of the string in the second case?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal It's probably unnecessary, but just habit to ensure [automatic semicolon assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186265/iife-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function) does not cause problems.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducer to the question. It reproduces the error in 100% of tries for me. Your code also does not work for me, I get the same error, both with firefox and chromium

Comment: You should probably compare versions of libraries, browsers and OS then. Could be a bug with specific versions (which you could then report to their GitHub)

Comment: I am also on Version 1.42.1

Comment: Thanks for responding and trying to provide a MCVE, but your updated code doesn't reproduce the issue for me--it's not materially different from my code in any obvious way (which makes sense because you get the error in both cases). "Bug in Playwright" doing the most basic task possible is _highly_ unlikely. You might want to try providing OS details or reinstalling Playwright. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 in case that helps. Responding to your edit, there's nothing strange about stringifying the function--that's necessary to get the function over to the browser context if it's not already a string.